# Get a list of users I have recently messaged Mysql

Tags: mysql

This is 'messages' table

```
---------------------------------
id  | sender  | receiver | seen |
---------------------------------
1   | john    |  jane    | 0    |   
2   | john    |  jane    | 1    |
3   | dave    |  john    | 0    |   <- John has received one unseen msg
4   | john    |  dave    | 1    |
5   | john    |  rose    | 0    |
```

---

I need to get a list of users john has interacted with. If john has any received unseen message, I need to highlight that message.

I tried this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        CASE WHEN sender = 'john' 
            THEN receiver
            ELSE sender 
        END userID
FROM    messages
WHERE   'john' IN (sender, receiver)
```

Output:

```
|jane|
|dave|
|rose|
```

Expected Output:

```
userID|seen|
|dave |  0 |
|jane |  1 |
|rose |  0 |
```

Comment: `I need to get a list of users john has interacted with` and `I need to highlight that message` are two totally different requirements.  Which one do you actually _need_ here?

Comment: I don't follow your expected output.  Why does the John-Rose record have a 1 in it?  There are no seen interactions between them in your source data.

Comment: john-Rose should have 0. Updated question.

Comment: John does not have any unseen messages from Rose, so why would you return 0 for Rose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not too clear, so I'll try to interpret it before providing an answer.

I believe, you would like to provide users with an overview of conversations with their counterparts by counterpart, highlighting those counterparts from which the particular user has an unread message.

This means, if the particular user **received** a message from a counterpart, which is not read, the query should return 0. In any other cases, the query should return 1. This also means, that if the particular user **only sent** a message, which is unread, the query still should return 1.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN sender = 'john' THEN receiver ELSE sender END as userID,
    COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN receiver = 'john' THEN seen ELSE null END), 1) AS seen
FROM messages
WHERE
    receiver = 'john' or sender = 'john'
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN sender = 'john' THEN receiver ELSE sender END;
```

Just to explain the main part of the code `COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN receiver = 'john' THEN seen ELSE null END), 1)`:

1. The `case` ensures that the calculation runs only on the received messages.
2. The `min()` ensures that if there is an unreserved message from a counterpart, then the expression returns 0.
3. The `coalesce()` takes care of those counterparties, who did not send any messages back to the current user. In this case the returned value is 1, to make sure that counterpart is not highlighted.